# My build pipeline not automatically triggered when I use folder/**/* as paths under trigger

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

My question is about Azure DevOps build pipeline. I wanted my build to automatically triggered when commit changes. So I include the files using Folder/**/* which any files under the folder including under subfolder. But when I commit changes in one of the file, my build does not triggered. But it worked when I use Folder/* instead. Can anyone explain what is the differences?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be by design. For the path filter, it could only recognize `/*` and not `/**/*`.

For paths:

- You may include `*` as the final character, but it doesn't do anything
  differently from specifying the directory name by itself.
- You may not include `*` in the middle of a path filter, and you may not
  use `?`.

This is stated in the Wildcards of this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards).

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible as it is written here [Support for wild cards in path filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters)

> Wild cards can be used when specifying inclusion and exclusion branches for CI or PR triggers in a pipeline YAML file. However, they cannot be used when specifying path filters. For instance, you cannot include all paths that match src/app/**/myapp*. This has been pointed out as an inconvenience by several customers. This update fills this gap. Now, you can use wild card characters (**, *, or ?) when specifying path filters.

The documentation is still not updated but you can use `Folder/**/*` in path filter.